# How can we override the voyager admin view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, voyager

I am facing the problem of overriding the voyager admin view because I don't want to show all fields in the view list. By default, it shows all table fields in the list and adds the scrollbar on the screen. like below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

*You can override any of the BREAD views for a single BREAD by creating a new folder in resources/views/vendor/voyager/slug-name where slug-name is the slug that you have assigned for that table. There are 4 files that you can override:
browse.blade.php
edit-add.blade.php
read.blade.php
order.blade.php
**Alternatively you can override the views for all BREADs by creating any of the above files under resources/views/vendor/voyager/bread***

[source](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Its helpful and I also found the solution for the same here https://voyager.devdojo.com/academy/views/ 

Thanks once again.

Comment: would be nice if you mark this answer, so it will help others